# Segmentation fault when trying to change foreground at QTableWidgetItem from a slot

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qtablewidget, qt-signals

I have an error when i try to dynamically create a table and it's items. And based on a state of **QComboBox** item I'm changing the background colour of **Qt:DisplayRole** item. The number of rows is random and could vary. Error occurs only after particular index of a row. Like when there is a 15 rows, it could or couldn't crash at 5th, 6th or maybe 14th row. It is always a random number and i can't understand why. And i understand that error could be related to a wrongly pointed index of an item. But when i was debugging my app qDebug() indexes were always correct

**Here is a slightly simplified example of my code:**

```cpp
QList<QTableWidget *> tableList; //Global variable;
QList<QComboBox *> comboBoxList; //Global variable;

int rowCount = 5;
int columnCount = 2;

tableList.append(new QTableWidget());
tableList.last()->setRowCount(rowCount);
tableList.last()->setColumnCount(columnCount);


for (int row = 0; row < tableList.last()->rowCount(); row++) 
{
    tableList.last()->setItem(row, 0, new QTableWidgetItem());
// This is the problematic item that causes segmentation fault \/
    tableList.last()->item(row, 0)->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, QVariant(1));

    QComboBox *tmpComboBox = new QComboBox();
// My stupid temporary workaround with row indexes that also could cause troubles, but overall it works
    tmpComboBox->setObjectName(QString::number(row));
    
    comboBoxList.append(tmpComboBox);
    comboBoxList.last()->addItem("on", "on");
    comboBoxList.last()->addItem("off", "off"); 
    tableList.last()->setItem(row, 1, comboBoxList.last())

    connect(comboBoxList->last(), SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onStateChanged(int)));

}

// Slot realisation
void Widget::onStateChanged(int stateIndex) 
{
   const int on = 0;
   const int off = 1;
// My stupid temporary workaround with row indexies that also could cause troubles, but overall it works
   int currentRow = sender()->objectName().toInt();

   if(stateIndex == off) 
   {
     //This is the place of crash
     tableList.at(someIndexOfExistingTable)->item(currentRow, 0)->setForeground(Qt::Gray)
   }
   else 
   {
     //Also the place
     tableList.at(someIndexOfExistingTable)->item(currentRow, 0)->setForeground(Qt::Black)
   }
}
```

I tried to catch an error and it only occurs on the last section of **setForeground()**. I expceted it to work with all items of the table. But it works only with a few of them. This error also repeats itself when i try to change **QFlags** of an item. I also tried to manually point an existing index of item but app also crashed with **SEGMENTATION FAULT**. ChatGPT didn't helped me either :)

Comment: You seem to have simplified *too much* – `Column` definition resulted int not being valid any more...

Comment: You probably want to add code to check the return value of `tableList.at(someIndexOfExistingTable)` and `item(currentRow, 0)` before dereferencing those pointers, since either of those methods could return `NULL`.  e.g.:  `QTableWidget * t = tableList.at(someIndexOfExistingTable);
QTableWidgetItem * i = t ? t->item(currentRow, 0) : NULL;
if (i) i->setForeground((stateIndex==off)?Qt::Gray:Qt::Black);`

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried checking for NULL and item is always there.